# Ux-Autocomplete Dark Mode

Tags: symfony, ux-symfony

I'm encountering an issue with ux-autocomplete in Symfony. I'm attempting to implement a dark mode, but after adding the classes "form-control dark-mode" or "bg-dark," the appearance is still too bright after running npm run build.

Does anyone have a solution to address this problem, please?

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Civil;
use App\Repository\CivilRepository;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\UX\Autocomplete\Form\AsEntityAutocompleteField;
use Symfony\UX\Autocomplete\Form\ParentEntityAutocompleteType;

#[AsEntityAutocompleteField]
class CivilAutocompleteField extends AbstractType
{
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'class' => Civil::class,
            'placeholder' => 'Choisir un civil',
            'choice_label' => 'name',
            'autocomplete' => true,
            'attr' => [
                'class' => 'form-control bg-dark text-white'
            ],
            //'security' => 'ROLE_SOMETHING',
        ]);
    }

    public function getParent(): string
    {
        return ParentEntityAutocompleteType::class;
    }
}
```